# How to debug SPNEGO on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, spnego

I have setup SPNEGO in tomcat.

I am getting the message  "Downgrade NTLM request to Basic Auth." and the client is prompted for user name and password.

But I want single sign on.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using a browser on the same host as your Tomcat, right?  SPNEGO does not work locally; only remotely.  This is the first thing to check, although there might be other reasons.

Comment: This is not corect. If the account and machine are in a domain and you request from local with full domain name, spnego will work flawlessly. Alex has another problem.

Answer (score 2):

SPNEGO is up and running. Obviously you don't know what SPNEGO exactly is. It simply wraps several technologies. E.g, Kerberos or NTLM crap. Since your server does not support Kerberos, it tries NTLM for some reason. double-check your env.